# Trying to subtract moment.js time values

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to subtract two strings that i have using moment.js, however the end result is NaN. Can someone explain what's going on? Here's the code in question:

```
totalOperationTime() {
  this.totalTime = this.elapsedTime - this.startTime;
}
```

In the example code above:
`this.elapsedTime` is `"12:17:34"`, `this.startTime` is `"12:17:29"`, but the end result - `this.totalTime` is `NaN`.
I believe the subtraction operator `-` converts strings to numbers, no?
I also tried converting said strings to numbers manually, but then
the end result - `this.totalTime` is `null`. 
The desired end result is a value that i can log in my mySQL DB similar to 
`"12:17:06"`, or `12:17:06`.

Comment: You need to convert them to `date`.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov If it's not too much trouble, can you post an example code please?

Comment: Convert them to `moment` object first.

Comment: Even though `-` converts string to number. `12:17:34` is not valid number.

If you are trying to get difference, you can use `.diff` from `momentjs`.

If you want to store it as Date object use `.toDate` from `moment`

Comment: _“I believe the subtraction operator - converts strings to numbers, no?”_ - it would, in easy cases like say `"15" - "12"`. But there is no way to convert `12:17:34` into a number that would actually make sense. parseInt or parseFloat would only get you `12` here, so even if the `-` operator did not refuse to apply the same magic here, the result would not be anything that would make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to convert your string into a moment object with

```
moment(myString, "HH:mm:ss");
```

Once it is done, you can compare the 2 moment objects by using the epoch milliseconds with `valueOf()`

```js
const elapsedTime = "12:17:34";
const startTime = "12:17:29"; 

const momentElapsedTime = moment(elapsedTime, "HH:mm:ss");
const momentStartTime = moment(startTime, "HH:mm:ss");

const totalTime = momentElapsedTime.valueOf() - momentStartTime.valueOf();

console.log("Total time in ms: " + totalTime);
console.log("Total time in s : " + totalTime/1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

You could also use the [`diff()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) method

```js
const elapsedTime = "12:17:34";
const startTime = "12:17:29"; 

const momentElapsedTime = moment(elapsedTime, "HH:mm:ss");
const momentStartTime = moment(startTime, "HH:mm:ss");

const totalTime = momentElapsedTime.diff(momentStartTime);

console.log("Total time in ms: " + totalTime);
console.log("Total time in s : " + totalTime/1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `new Date()` to convert your time string to date:

```
const time1 = '12:17:06'
const time2 = '12:18:56'

const dateTime1 = new Date('1970-01-01T' + time1 + 'Z');
const dateTime2 = new Date('1970-01-01T' + time2 + 'Z');

const differenceInMilliSec = dateTime2 - dateTime1;
```

We used `1970-01-01T` because it can be any date, the only thing we should be care of is that for both times date should be the same.